# How to edit list elements in kotlin or add to second list?

Tags: list, kotlin

I tried to edit a list in-place but wasn't able to get it working. Now trying to edit individual elements and add them to a second list. However the second list remains null and does not get updated. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        var localFiles: MutableList<String> = File(localPath).list().toMutableList()
        var localFileDates: MutableList<String>? = null
        val iterateLocal = localFileDates?.listIterator()
        for (item in localFiles) {
            var date = item.takeLast(10).take(6)
            if (date.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex()) and (date.length == 6) and (date != null) and (date != "null")) {
                iterateLocal?.add(item.takeLast(10).take(6))
            }
        }
        println(networkFiles) // prints correct outpu
        println(localFileDates) // prints null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need init localFileDates variable:
var localFileDates = MutableList()

```
var localFiles: MutableList<String> = File(localPath).list().toMutableList()
    var localFileDates = MutableList<String>()
    val iterateLocal = localFileDates?.listIterator()
    for (item in localFiles) {
        var date = item.takeLast(10).take(6)
        if (date.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex()) and (date.length == 6) and (date != null) and (date != "null")) {
            iterateLocal?.add(item.takeLast(10).take(6))
        }
    }
    println(networkFiles) // prints correct outpu
    println(localFileDates) // prints correct
```

Comment: Changing from `var localFileDates: MutableList<String>? = null` to `var localFileDates: MutableList<String>? = mutableListOf()` worked perfectly. I doubt I would have figured this out without help.

Comment: Java written with Kotlin syntax. This is not how Kotlin is meant to be used :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `map{..}` function to create a copy of the list with updated values.

```
val localFiles = File(localPath).list()?.toMutableList() ?: listOf()
val localFileDates = localFiles.mapNotNull { item ->
  val date = item.takeLast(10).take(6)
  if (date.matches("[0-9]{6}".toRegex()) {
    date
  } else {
    null
  }
}

println(localFiles)
println(localFileDates)
```

I use the `mapNotNull{..}` function calls the block for every element of the list and builds the new list only from non-null values.

You do not need `var` in your code, explicit type names can be omitted too.

The condition can be simplified - no need for the null check, the regular expression filters our the `data == "null"` case, the length check can be included into the regex too. The `date` variable can be re-used too.

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic (and readable) way:

```
val localFileDates = File(localPath).list().map { it.takeLast(10).take(6) }.filter {
    it.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex()) && (it.length == 6) && (it != "null")
}
```

Also I suggest you create a named function for `takeLast(10).take(6)` and the condition to make it clear what is the intent of these lines of code.